# Cancel and Reschedule a Local Notification(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift2, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to show a local notification with a time interval of 1 day (24 hours) and its working fine but now I want to cancel notification for a specific day. I tried(today) this but it didn't seem to work. My notification is still appearing this is what I have done for cancelling the notification:

```
let appNotification = appDelegate!.notification

UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(appNotification)
```

This is how am scheduling the notification in `appDelegate` :

```
//scheduling notification

dateComp.year = 2015;
dateComp.month = 01;
dateComp.day = 20;
dateComp.hour = 21;
dateComp.minute = 05;
dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
notification.alertBody = "my daily notiification ?"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.fireDate  = finalFireDate
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day

let dateNow = NSDate()
let noticalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: dateNow)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

I don't know why am not able to cancel the notification there's anything that is missing or doing wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

Try this code

```
var app:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
    var notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
    if notification.fireDate == "your date" {
        //Cancelling local notification
        app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for responding :) , but the problem is i don't have so many notification i have a single notification which is repeating itself every single day so the fireDate is a single  same date , so using your solution will not going to work correct me if am wrong @Madhumitha

Comment: Its cancelling the Local Notification but does not cancelling custom sound as its playing continuously around 3 to 4 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the notification's `userInfo` property.

For example, if you schedule it like this:

```
notificationID = 1
notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
// other settings...
notification.userInfo = ["NotificationID": notificationID]
```

You can use `userInfo` to find it:

```
let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
let scheduledNotifications = application.scheduledLocalNotifications!

for notification in scheduledNotifications {
  if let nID = notification.userInfo?["NotificationID"] as? Int {
    if nID == appDelegate!.notificationID {
      application.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
      break
    }
  }
}
```