# SkScene update method interrupted by push notifications, how can i detect the interruption

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, apple-push-notifications

I have a simple game app, which is programmed with SpriteKit. The Problem is, when a push notifications (SMS,iMessage etc) appears, the game stutters because the **update:forScene: method is not called.**
To avoid this i want to implement a simple pause menu, which will be shown as soon as a push message comes in.

**How can i detect if a push message interrupts the app? In AppDelegate application:willResignActive is also not called.**

It would be the best if the game continues when the message comes in, if there is another solution to force the update method to be called.

Had anybody the same Problem?

Answer (score 4):

You should not try to resume your game when an interruption is happening, you should pause it, otherwise its not a good user experience.

For iMessages, phone calls etc you usually use the method you said doesn't work. 
I use NSNotificationCenter to pause my games, you can google about it, there is plenty tutorials.

Essentially in your game scene add a NSNotificationCenter observer.
Also create a property for that observers name to avoid typos later on.

```
let pauseGameKey = "PauseGameKey" // above class so you can access it anywhere in project

class GameScene: SKScene {

    // add this in didMoveToView
    // in #selector add the method you want to get called
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourPauseGameMethod), name: pauseGameKey, object: nil)
}
```

Than create the willMoveFromView method so you can remove the observer when you transition to another scene (good practice).

```
   override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
   }
```

Than in app delegate post the notification when the application will resign.

```
 func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(pauseGameKey, object: nil)
}
```

For local and remote UINotifications you can additional use these 2 methods in app delegate.

```
/// Local notification
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

}

/// Remote notification
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank You, i tried the methods, but how can i filter the notifications? (i more than one per second...)

Comment: You can use the local notifications user info. This question has been asked and answered already. I use Viktors answer by giving each notification a unique ID. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224367/cancel-and-reschedule-a-local-notification-swift

Comment: You cannot filter for iMessage etc as far as I believe. Not sure why applicationWillResignActive is not working for you.Thats normally the spot for these type of notifications

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of how I pause my game when interruptions coming in. I bet you are making a mistake (very  common mistake) in how you are trying to call your game scene from your appDelegate.